# How to call a returned value from the same JAVA class

Tags: java, function, class, call

I was doing the time comparison project, and i used a really dumb way to do it. Please see the code below:

In the function called getInDays, I have calculated how many days per year, and set the days. However, in the next function called getInHours, days cannot be used. Can somebody help me?

Thank you so much!

PS: I have deleted all the other functions in order to make this code easy to see.

```
package datetimeexample;

public class DateTime {
    private int month;
    private int day;
    private int year;
    private Time time;


    public void getInDays()
    {
        int days = year * 365 + month * 31 + day;
    }

    public void getInHours()
    {
        int totalHours = days*12 + time.getHour();
    }


}
```

Comment: Get use to using parentheses (), this isn't your problem, but it will make everything a lot easier to read....The problem is as swithen colaco has answered, also at present your code makes no sense, you are declaring local variables, but you don't return the results, change the type from void to int and return the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

days is a declared within the getInDays() method. The scope of days is local to the getInDays() methods.It cannot be accessed from outside that method.

You have 2 options.

1. Declare `days` outside the getInDays() methods and make its scope instance level.
2. Instead of using `days` in getInHours() call getInDays() directly. (Provided you change the return type of the method.

[Check this link for more info](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-scope-in-java/)

Comment: Thank you so much!
One more question: Is there some other ways to compare times except this one?

Comment: You will need to share the entire source code for that. Please pose this question as new post as it is unrelated to the current question. Mark the answer correct if right.